# Naming convention of functions in Ocaml

Tags: naming-conventions, ocaml

As Ocaml does not accept function overloading, sometimes I have to define some similar functions for different types. For instance,

```
let reduce_a (a: A): A = ...
let reduce_b (b: B): B = ...

let a_compare (a0: A) (a1: A): bool = ...
let b_compare (b0: B) (b1: B): bool = ...
```

I know that the best way is to have two modules `A` and `B`, and make 2 functions `A.reduce` and `B.reduce`. But before creating modules, I just would like to know the best convention to name a function.

Do people usually prefer to name `reduce_a` (the verb before the type) or `a_reduce` (the type before the verb)? Can we find some examples in the standard libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the `a_compare` format to be far more used than `compare_a`, including the OCaml compiler itself, so you might as well use that convention. There are not any actual benefits, except perhaps cosmetic alignment, and the fact that it "feels" like a namespace.

Note that this is far more often employed for labels in record types and constructors in variant types, than it is for functions.

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative is to put them in their own modules, like

```
module A = struct

    type t = ...
    let reduce x = ...
    let compare x y = ...

end

module B = struct ... (* you get the point *) end
```

In this way you don't need to worry about if the function is `compare_a` or `a_compare`, since it has to be `A.compare`. You'll have to restrain yourself from (other then locally) opening the modules. Of course the work-ability of this solution depends on the types you are dealing with.